# Akka: create actor if not exists

Tags: akka

From [this](https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/01/now-you-see-me--now-you-dont--linkedins-real-time-presence-platf) interesting article about the LinkedIn Presence platform, we have:

> ...we create an Actor for the member if it doesn’t already exist...

For me, this glosses over a whole host of issues with how to do "create if not exists" in a distributed environment. Clearly there are CAP trade offs here, for example, AmazonS3 does not support create if not exists semantics.

Using Akka, how can we create an actor only if it does not exist already *without creating a single point of failure* which must have synchronized access to global state such as a map of member id to actor?

Note that using a supervisor actor to do the get-or-create is not an acceptable solution because that negates the point of having a distributed system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use cluster sharding then this is handled by default. The shard coordinator will take care of creating the entity actor if its not available and forward the message to it. Its its already available then it simply sends the message to it. You also get location transparency because the coordinator knows in which node the particular shard entity actor exists.

Regards,

Vinoth